# Postgres stemming throwing out matches

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

The query

`SELECT to_tsvector('recreation') @@ to_tsquery('recreatio:*');`

returns false even though 'recreati' is a prefix of 'recreation'. This seems to happen because 'recreation' is stored as its stem, 'recreat'. For example, if we deliberately break the stemming algorithm by running

`SELECT to_tsvector('recreation1') @@ to_tsquery('recreatio:*');`

the query returns true.

Is there a way to make the first query match?

Comment: Interesting point. The interaction of wildcard matches and stemming can be problematic. Other than using the `simple` dictionary (and then losing stemming when you want it) I'm not sure if there's a good solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answer is useful given the age of the question, but:

## Concerning stemming

It seems you are right:

```
select ts_lexize('english_stem','recreation');
```

outputs

```
 ts_lexize
-----------
 {recreat}
(1 row)
```

and the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/textsearch-controls.html) says

> Also, * can be attached to a lexeme to specify prefix matching:
>
> `SELECT to_tsquery('supern:*A & star:A*B');`
>
> Such a lexeme will match any word in a tsvector that begins with the given string.

So it seems there is no way to make original query match.

## A solution based on partial matching

One could fallback to looking for partial matches of the stems and the query, e.g. using [`pg_trgm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html) extension:

```
SELECT (to_tsvector('recreation creation') @@ to_tsquery('recreatio:*')) or 
  'recreatio:*' % any (
    select trim(both '''' from regexp_split_to_table(strip(to_tsvector('recreation creation'))::text, ' '))
  );
```

(Maybe the array of stems can be formed in a more elegant way.)